# Calling RCTDirectEventBlock doesn't trigger JS code

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm attempting to write a native UI component for react-native, and I'm having some trouble figuring out how the event system works. I've read through the documentation, and unfortunately it wasn't particularly helpful mostly because it is specific to obj-c with which I'm not very comfortable. Also not very comfortable with Swift, but it's the language I'm trying to learn at the moment. The code below is what I have so far, and my application loads just fine (no issues in XCode).

CustomViewManager.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc(CustomViewManager)
class CustomViewManager : RCTViewManager {
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return CustomView();
  }
}
```

CustomViewManagerBridge.m

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CustomViewManager, RCTViewManager)

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onPress, RCTDirectEventBlock)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(list, NSArray)

@end
```

CustomView.h

```
#import "RCTView.h"
@interface CustomView : RCTView
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray *list;
@property (nonatomic, copy) RCTDirectEventBlock onPress;
@end
```

CustomView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc(CustomView)
class CustomView : UIView {

  var list: [CGFloat]? {
    didSet {
      print("set list")
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame);
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func setOnPress(callback: RCTDirectEventBlock) {
    print("set onPress", callback)
    let dict:[NSObject:AnyObject] = [
      "hello": "world",
      ]
    callback(dict)
  }

}
```

And then calling it from react using the code below:

```
<CustomView list={[1,2,3]} onPress={data => console.log('js', data)} />
```

This works fine to an extent. I can access the props which are passed from the swift code. I get the list, and the onPress function. **However, when I call the `callback` the `console.log` is not triggered and I'm not quite sure why.** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gordan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Turns out that I was using the incorrect property type. Changing `RCTDirectEventBlock` to `RCTBubblingEventBlock` did the trick.